# MySQL Trigger Syntax Error IF Exists

Tags: mysql, if-statement, triggers, exists

I have a MySQL Trigger I am trying to create, but can't get the syntax right.

The trigger should go through and match a set of keywords against the title of the new post inserted into the database. If it finds a match, it should assign the new post to that bucket and update the buckets set of keywords. If it does not find a match, it should create a new bucket using values from the post. The errors point to the line beginning with IF EXISTS, but I can't figure out what's wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

---

UPDATE: Code has been updated to pull out IF EXISTS, but now I am getting an error starting at the ELSE statement.

```
delimiter $$

CREATE TRIGGER bucket_trigger_v1 BEFORE INSERT ON posts
FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    set @target = NEW.post_title;
    set @bucket_id_number = '';
    set @bucket_relevance = '';

    SELECT idbuckets, MATCH (keywords) AGAINST (@target) AS score INTO @bucket_id_number, @bucket_relevance FROM buckets WHERE MATCH (keywords) AGAINST (@target) ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 1;
    IF (@bucket_id_number != '') THEN
      BEGIN
        SET NEW.buckets_idbuckets = @bucket_id_number;
        UPDATE buckets SET keywords = concat(keywords, @target) WHERE idbuckets = @bucket_id_number;
      END
      ELSE
      BEGIN
        INSERT INTO buckets (idbuckets, keywords, creationdate) VALUES (, @target, NEW.postdate);
        SET NEW.bucket_idbuckets = (SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID());
      END
    END IF;
END;

$$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL, or at least the version I'm running, can't handle multiple triggers at once. The IF statement doesn't work with BEGIN and END because of this, and so I'll have to find a different solution.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of points to consider:

[13.2.9.1. SELECT ... INTO Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-into.html)

> An INTO clause should not be used in a nested SELECT because such a
>   SELECT must return its result to the outer context.

[19.3.1. Trigger Syntax and Examples](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html)

> Such a SET statement has no effect in an AFTER trigger because the row change will have already occurred.

**UPDATE**

The following code creates correctly the trigger. The `posts` table is created only in order to create the trigger.

```sql
/*Table structure for table `posts` */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `posts`;

CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `post_title` VARCHAR(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `buckets_idbuckets` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `postdate` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=INNODB;

/* Trigger structure for table `posts` */

DELIMITER $$

/*!50003 DROP TRIGGER*/ /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ /*!50003 `bucket_trigger_v1` */$$

CREATE TRIGGER `bucket_trigger_v1` BEFORE INSERT ON `posts`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET @target := new.`post_title`;
    SET @bucket_id_number := '';
    SET @bucket_relevance := '';
    SELECT `idbuckets`, MATCH (`keywords`) AGAINST (@target) AS `score` INTO @bucket_id_number, @bucket_relevance FROM `buckets` WHERE MATCH (`keywords`) AGAINST (@target) ORDER BY `score` DESC LIMIT 1;
    IF (@bucket_id_number != '') THEN
        SET new.`buckets_idbuckets` := @bucket_id_number;
        UPDATE `buckets` SET `keywords` = CONCAT(`keywords`, @target) WHERE `idbuckets` = @bucket_id_number;
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO `buckets` (`keywords`, `creationdate`) VALUES (@target, new.`postdate`);
        SET new.`buckets_idbuckets` := LAST_INSERT_ID();
    END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I updated the code to remove the into clause, but now I am getting another error at the ELSE portion of the code. I appreciate your help.

Comment: The `INSERT` statement has an error, missing the first value to be inserted.

Comment: That value is an AUTO_INCREMENT column. Do I need to put something specific there? I thought it would auto fill.

Comment: A sentence also like the following should work: `INSERT INTO buckets (keywords, creationdate) VALUES (@target, NEW.postdate);`

Comment: Appreciate it, I think I figured it out though. I'll post the answer.

Comment: @Drizzit12 I updated the answer with a code that successfully creates the trigger. I hope you find it useful.